how to call localhost url in telerik report API project?
I have one telerik project in that i have webReportDesigner.html and second project is TelerikReportAPI. how to call localhost url in API project ?
i am trying to fetch TelerikReportUI .I tried below code :
$("#webReportDesigner").telerik_WebReportDesigner({
      toolboxArea: {
          layout: "list" //Change to "grid" to display the contents of the Components area in a flow grid layout.
      },
      serviceUrl: "http://localhost:7000/api/TelerikReports"}

i am getting below error:
jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).telerik_WebReportDesigner is not a function TypeError: $(...).telerik_WebReportDesigner is not a function

